# ConnectionStrings of Mysql in app.config generating NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net

`NullReferenceExeception` is generating while obtaing **connectionString** from `app.config`

Connection String i am creating as:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connect" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;user id=customer;password=hassaan09;database=customer" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

but in retrieving connection string exception is generating which i used:

```
public List<customer> LoadGridView()
{
    List<customer> lstCustomer = new List<customer>();

    try
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connect"].ConnectionString; //Here exception is generating
        // string connectionString = "server=localhost;port=3306;user id=customer;password=hassaan09;database=customer"; //if i directly provide connectionstring it will work fine  
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select customerid,name,email,age from customerinfo", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    return lstCustomer;
}
```

Comment: At a guess, I would say for some reason the `app.config` file isn't being deployed with your exe. Add a breakpoint on the first line in the `try` block, then when you hit the breakpoint, add a watch for `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` - is this empty?

Comment: yes i have added breakpoint it is increasing the count, iam getting count = 2 but the connectionString it is providing null

Comment: I assume that this is not a web application right?

Comment: Confused that you see `count = 2` as there is only one entry in the `app.config` example?

Comment: 1 connection is from server explorer and the another connection i am using in app.config and its a windows form. i am still figuring out why it is not reading connectionstring